# Preverification failed with error code -2147483645

Tags: java, java-me

I was doing some j2mee work on ubuntu linux with Netbeans 6.7.1. I went fine until my notebook  broken down. So, I had to move my work on another pc with windows XP on it. All went fine with netbeans settings, etc. However, When I try to build my code, I got error:

```
E:\silent\kl_stuffs\jagoankomik\nbproject\build-impl.xml:461: Preverification failed with error code -2147483645.
```

Here's the ant XML snippet (auto generated by netbeans, I don't really know how to create it myself):

```
<target name="pre-preverify"/>
<target name="do-preverify" if="cldc-platform.trigger">
    <fail unless="preverify.classes.dir">Must set preverify.classes.dir</fail>
    <mkdir dir="${preverify.sources.dir}"/>
    <copy todir="${preverify.sources.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${buildsystem.baton}" includes="**/*.class"/>
    </copy>
    <mkdir dir="${preverify.classes.dir}"/>
    <nb-preverify srcdir="${preverify.sources.dir}" destdir="${preverify.classes.dir}" classpath="${platform.bootclasspath}:${extra.classpath}" configuration="${platform.configuration}" platformhome="${platform.home}" platformtype="${platform.type}" commandline="${platform.preverifycommandline}"/>
    <copy todir="${preverify.classes.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${buildsystem.baton}" defaultexcludes="${filter.use.standard}" excludes="${filter.excludes.evaluated},${build.classes.excludes}"/>
    </copy>
    <nb-overrideproperty name="buildsystem.baton" value="${preverify.classes.dir}"/>
</target>
<target name="post-preverify"/>
```

My question is, how do I work around this? because I got no result from google:(. If possible, I want to skip preverify section. Do you guys know how to do this?

UPDATE: As requested, here's full build log:

```
pre-init:
pre-load-properties:
exists.config.active:
exists.netbeans.user:
exists.user.properties.file:
load-properties:
exists.platform.active:
exists.platform.configuration:
exists.platform.profile:
basic-init:
cldc-pre-init:
cldc-init:
cdc-init:
ricoh-pre-init:
ricoh-init:
semc-pre-init:
semc-init:
savaje-pre-init:
savaje-init:
sjmc-pre-init:
sjmc-init:
cdc-hi-pre-init:
cdc-hi-init:
nokiaS80-pre-init:
nokiaS80-init:
nsicom-pre-init:
nsicom-init:
post-init:
init:
conditional-clean-init:
conditional-clean:
deps-jar:
pre-preprocess:
do-preprocess:
Pre-processing 0 file(s) into E:\silent\kl_stuffs\jagoankomik\build\preprocessed directory.
post-preprocess:
preprocess:
pre-compile:
extract-libs:
do-compile:
post-compile:
compile:
pre-obfuscate:
proguard-init:
skip-obfuscation:
proguard:
post-obfuscate:
obfuscate:
lwuit-build:
pre-preverify:
do-preverify:
Preverifying 6 file(s) into E:\silent\kl_stuffs\jagoankomik\build\preverified directory.
E:\silent\kl_stuffs\jagoankomik\nbproject\build-impl.xml:461: Preverification failed with error code -2147483645.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't skip preverification for j2me builds -- so you'll have to find a way to resolve this issue. Here's one of the first few google hits explaining what preverification is and why it's important: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=201507

A few thoughts re: your log:

1) so it seems like netbeans is running ant for builds there -- you should be able to enable verbose mode equivalent to running ant from console with -v param. That might shed some light on what's going on

2) This thread (http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5374546) indicates that obfuscation settings may be causing something like that.

3) Actually -- just thought about this: do you have preverify installed on your windows machine in the first place? Search for preverify and see if it's anywhere to be found. Then make sure that Netbeans knows where to look for preverify. If you don't have it, you should install it as a part of whatever J2ME SDK you're using.

Comment: Hi, I've added full build log to my question. However, that log doesn't print any error / notice / warning except the one that got me post this question.

Comment: "do you have windows installed on your windows machine in the first place".  Try replacing it with Linux :-)

Comment: @Stephen: Nope, it's pure windows. Btw, I install netbeans on another pc, setting it the way I setting it on previous pc. But, I got no error when compiling!

Comment: oops, i meant "do you have preverify installed..." :) this initially said "do you have ... on your linux machine", then i realized that you were on windows, then i edited to replace "linux" with "windows" and apparently ended up replacing something with "windows" twice :)

anyway, double-check if netbeans can find your preverify, and try to get verbose output of your ant build as i say in #1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the cause was that I had made a mistake writing the name of the package in the first line of my java classes (I used a Capital letter and not the normal letter!).

NOTE : Another information that I've gathered from other forum posts: the same problem could arise if you have set CLDC1.0 for your project, you should try instead CLDC1.1